# vscode cloud code k8s debugging with istio

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, istio, vscode-debugger

Trying to use vscode and cloud code to debug in GKE with istio.  Not seeing any errors, but breakpoints are not being hit and application is responding.

```
[install-python-support] Installing runtime debugging support files in /dbg
[install-python-support] Installation complete
[hello-app-sm-py]  * Serving Flask app "hello_app_sm_py_v3" (lazy loading)
[hello-app-sm-py]  * Environment: production
[hello-app-sm-py] [31m   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.[0m
[hello-app-sm-py] [2m   Use a production WSGI server instead.[0m
[hello-app-sm-py]  * Debug mode: on
[hello-app-sm-py]  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
[hello-app-sm-py]  * Restarting with stat
[hello-app-sm-py]  * Debugger is active!
[hello-app-sm-py]  * Debugger PIN: 292-496-499
```